# batch rename file names including spaces and patterns

Tags: rename

I would like to rename a bunch of files which are named in a general form of,

`text1 text2 [firstname.lastname] text3 ... textn.ext`

I want to remove the text `[firstname.lastname]` from the name of a file. To simplify the task, assume that `[firstname.lastname]` is a fixed first and last name for all the files.

I use Ubuntu 12.04, and I tried the following command,

`$ find . -name "*.ext" -print | xargs sed -i 's/[firstname.lastname]//g'`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: A couple of notes: You don't have to use the `-print` command with `find`. Printing the filenames is the default behavior. you can use `find`'s `-exec` flag instead of `xargs`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41740/find-exec-vs-find-xargs-which-one-to-choose

Comment: I disagree. There are different problems presented here than in the other question. Only [one answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files) to the other question comes close to answering this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) modifies a file's contents. Use [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) instead.

```
$ find . -name "*.ext" -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/\[firstname\.lastname\]//g'
```

Pass `rename` the `-n` flag to make it do a dry run. That way, you can test your command without actually renaming any files.

I also made a couple of other changes to the code.

- Adding `-print0` to `find` and `-0` to `xargs` allows the command to handle spaces. By default, `find` uses newlines to separate the filenames it outputs and `xargs` expects to receive filenames separated by whitespace. `-print0` and `-0` make these two commands treat null bytes as filename delimiters. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81349/how-do-i-use-find-when-the-filename-contains-spaces) for more information.
- `rename` uses [Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), which treat `.`, `[`, and `]` specially. They must be escaped in this case.

Comment: I created a test file `text1 [firstname.lastname].txt`, executing your command generates the following error: `Can't rename ./text1 /x1: No such file or directory` followed by `Can't rename [firstname.lastname].txt []x: No such file or directory`

Comment: Escape the `[` `]` braces: `\[firstname\.lastname\]`. I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Escaping the `[` and `]` does not help since the problem is that `find` has a problem with spaces. It does not include a space as part of a file name.

Comment: @Rasoul: Spaces are another problem. You need to add `-print0` to `find` (replace `-print`) and `-0` to `xargs`. Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81349/how-do-i-use-find-when-the-filename-contains-spaces.

Comment: @Rasoul: I have edited my answer to include the extra information.

Answer (score 4):

Using Bash globbing:

```
for i in *.ext; do
    echo mv -nv -- "$i" "${i/firstname.lastname/}"
done
```

Remove the echo if you're happy with it.

---

If you need to go into subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.ext; do
    echo mv -nv -- "$i" "${i/firstname.lastname/}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` when you're happy with it.

---

Using `find`:

```
find . -name '*.ext' -exec bash -c 'echo mv -nv -- "$0" "${0/firstname.lastname/}"' {} \;
```

Remove the `echo` when you're happy with it.

---

How about a method that will rename, removing any pattern of the form `xxx.yyy` (so it will remove the `firstname.lastname` of the filename, being `john.doe` or `james.brown`): for this (using the first method):

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in *.ext; do
    echo mv -nv -- "$i" "${i/+([[:graph:]])\.+([[:graph]])/}"
done
```

or using the second method:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob
for i in **/*.ext; do
    echo mv -nv -- "$i" "${i/+([[:graph:]])\.+([[:graph:]])/}"
done
```

or using the `find` method:

```
find . -name '*.ext' -exec bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; echo mv -nv -- "$0" "${0/+([[:graph:]])\.+([[:graph:]])/}"' {} \;
```

If the `firstname.lastname` pattern is always enclosed between spaces, you could also use the pattern substitution:

```
"${i/*([[:space:]])+([[:graph:]])\.+([[:graph:]])*([[:space:]])/ }"
```

so as to only leave one space.

---

*Note.* All these methods are 100% safe regarding filenames with spaces and other funny symbols.