# shell for loop with find with filenames containing spaces

Tags: shell-script, find, filenames, whitespace

Consider a directory with typical Microsoft Windows filenames:

```
New Document.txt
Foo.doc
Foo - Copy.doc
```

I'd like to do something on each file such as:

```
for sendfile in $(find ${POLLDIR} -type f -mmin +1 -print0)
do
  echo \"${sendfile}\"
  ls -l "${sendfile}"
  and-so-on
  if success_above
  then
    mv "${sendfile}" "${donedir}/."
  fi
done
```

Please note that I don't want to just run 1 command with "${sendfile}" as the argument. I need the loop to do error checking and other things (like moving "${sendfile}" on success and logging on failure).

What is a "correct" construct to escape/quote the filenames from find so I can use them in a for look like in the `ls` command above? If possible, I'd like to avoid storing the filenames in a temp file one by one.

I don't think that `find -printf '"%p"\n'` as suggested by triplee in the comments to question [ [How do I use find when the filename contains spaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81349/5923) ] would work in a `for foo in $(...) do` construct.

I think replacing "illegal" chars with `?` would work for me in this case, but it would be very ugly. The for loop ultimately processes files in ${POLLDIR} and then moves them when done, so the chance of "Foo bar.txt" colliding with "Foo-bar.txt" is 0 (-ish).

My best attempt so far is:

```
for sendfile in $(find ${POLLDIR} -type f -mmin +1 -print | tr ' ' '?')
do
  ...
done
```

Any cleaner suggestions?

Comment: You rarely find a `for loop` and `find` construction together. I think you want something like `find "$POLLDIR" -type f -mmin +1 -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$@" ./target' _ {} +`  You can use `-name` flag to specify different extensions etc. No need for the loop at all.

Comment: The problem is that I can't write the entire for loop body as `-exec` arguments.

Comment: As I said, you don't need a for loop there. You have not explained why you'd need a for loop. Unless I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: @val0x00ff I tried to explain it: "I don't want to run just 1 command, I need the loop to do error checking and other things"..."and logging on failure". This is too much for `-exec` IMHO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `find ... -print0 | while IFS="" read -d ""` construct:

```
find "${POLLDIR}" -type f -mmin +1 -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" sendfile
  do
    echo "${sendfile}"
    ls -l "${sendfile}"
    and-so-on
    if success_above
      then
        mv "${sendfile}" "${donedir}/."
    fi
done
```

The `-d ""` sets the end of line character to null (`\0`), which is what separates each filename found by `find ... -print0` and the `IFS=""` is needed to also work with filenames that contain newlines - according to POSIX only slashes (`/`) and null (`\0`) are forbidden. The `-r` ensures that backslashes do not escape characters (so that `\t` for example matches an actual backslash followed by a `t` and not a tab).

Comment: This is a perfect match. I had forgotten about `read -d`. Thanks!

Comment: I regret that I have only one upvote to give! Thank you to the answerer, I was giving up hope that this was possible at all.