# Rsync files by date

Tags: bash, find, rsync

I have this file structure:

```
...folders/to/copy
...folders/to/mirror
```

I've been doing:

```
rsync --ignore-existing -raz --progress $source $destination
```

This is serving well for the purpose of keeping everything up to date on both folder trees. But now I have the need to do this only for files that have been changed more than 24 hours ago. I have tried something like this:

```
rsync -rav `find $source -mtime 1` $destination
```

The problem is this messes up the file tree and doesn't work as I need. Is there a better way to do this?

I want to backup the file structure, using the relative paths say from "folders" and everything in it, from one place to another leaving only files older than 24 hours (`mtime`).

Comment: `find $source -mtime 1` lists files and directories and links and sockets and ... which were "modified" between 24 hours and 48 hours ago. You probably don't want to list directories, and you may not want to have the 48 hour restriction as well.

Comment: That's my problem, I don't want to list the files just want to "signal" rsync that only files that have been modified more than 24 hours ago are clear to be backed up.

Comment: the -a is doing recursion.  So if your `find` adds any directories, the rsync will run all the items underneath.  You'd at least want to turn that off.

Comment: Thanks @BowlOfRed, that was the point I was trying to make when I said "You probably don't want to list directories" but you expressed it better.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find | rsync` to filter the files you're interested in copying, like this

```
src=/source/folders/to/./copy
dst=/destination/mirrored/folders

find "$src/" -type f -mtime +0 -print0 |
    rsync --dry-run -a -iv --files-from - --from0 / "$dst"
```

Remove the `--dry-run` when you're happy with the set of results. Remove `-iv` if you want a quieter operation.

I should point out that the `/./` part of the source path defines the point from which the file paths should be retained. For example, if you have a path `/source/folders/to/./copy/sub/here.txt` then the corresponding destination will become `/destination/mirrored/folders/copy/sub/here.txt`. See the `--files-from` and `--relative` (`-R`) options in the `man rsync` documentation for the details. If your source path is relative that will work too.

This solution presupposes GNU `find` or some other variant that offers `-print0`. If you don't have that option, you could also remove `--from0`, but better would be to replace `-print0` with `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`. See the discussion at [POSIX alternative to GNU find's -print0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/632877/100397).

Comment: This is perfect, it works exactly as needed just need relative paths. Thank you!

Comment: @Acidorr your question showed absolute paths so that's what I gave here. Provide more detail in your question and I'll see if I can update this answer for you

Comment: Many thanks, just did the edit it should be more detailed now!

Comment: @Acidorr relative files now included

Comment: this won't work if you want to deal with deleted files, no?

Comment: @Michael have you considered `--delete-excluded`? That might address your concern